# Why does git indicate that files are modified after checkout?

Tags: git, git-checkout

In terminal I just did:

```
git checkout -b feature123
```

Then I see

```
M   Classes/API/APIClient/APIClient.swift
M   Classes/Data/Data.swift
M   Classes/Views/StackProvider.swift
M   Tests/ViewModelTests.swift
Switched to a new branch 'feature123'
```

Yet when I do:

```
git status
```

I get:

```
On branch feature123
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Is that expected?

I didn't change anything so the `git status` is understandable, but I can't understand the `M` for those files.

This has happened a few times...

**EDIT:**

This is how my bash_profile looks like:

```
[ -f /usr/local/etc/bash_completion ] && . /usr/local/etc/bash_completion
alias xi='cd ~/Documents/xi’
alias xdd='rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData'
alias xpush='pod repo push ios-pod-spec mypod.podspec --private --allow-warnings --verbose'
# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
if [ -f '/Users/honey/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc' ]; then . '/Users/honey/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'; fi

# The next line enables shell command completion for gcloud.
if [ -f '/Users/honey/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc' ]; then . '/Users/honey/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc'; fi
~                                                                                                                                                                                          
~                                                                                                                                                                                          
~                                                                                                                                                                                          
~                                                                                                                                                                                          
~                                                                                                                                                                                          
~
```

Comment: That's not expected.  Any chance your bash_profile is overriding one of your commands?  Is this a new problem or workflow for you?

Comment: I included my `bash_profile`, but I don't think there's anything related there

Comment: It's very hard to say why this is happening without access to the repository, and sometimes to your particular machine (to test file name case folding and line-ending settings). Typical causes involve file systems that believe that files named `README` and `readme` are *the same* file (Git regards them as different files) and configurations that fiddle with line-endings, replacing LF-only with CRLF for instance.

Comment: @torek I have a private framework that I develop and test that with my sample app. I wonder if that can cause any issues. I may point to the framework locally or maybe directly to a frameworks's branch. Ultimately I point to a tag. Not sure if that can cause issues.